# Get a list of multiple types using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Using MVC4 with Entoty Framework CodeFirst I am having problems with the following scenario:

```
public class Survey
{

    public QuestionCollection Questions {get;set;}
}

public class QuestionCollection : List<IQuestion> //Just for MVC
{ }

public class QuestionType1 : IQuestion { ... }
public class QuestionType2 : IQuestion { ... }
```

Seems straightforward. Now in my controller I want to get the Survey so i have:

```
DataContext context = new DataContext ();

var survey = context.Surveys.Include(s => s.Questions).SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
```

It does compile but runtime it gives me the error:

A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Survey' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Questions'.

What am I doing wrong here?
Is there any good tutorial on this topic?

Comment: I think that the interface may be the problem.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805329/how-to-use-interface-properties-with-codefirst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework Code First requires that navigation collections be declared as an `ICollection<T>`. Also, to enable lazy loading of the associations, it should be virtual. This is because, unless otherwise specified, EF will return a proxy object wrapping your declared class. Since your original `QuestionCollection` property is a concrete implementation, it can't override that in the proxy and enable the navigation. `Questions` has to be declared as the interface.

Your concerns and requirements in EF are different than in MVC, and they aren't always compatible. If you really, really wanted `QuestionCollection`, you'll have to map that.

Your Surveys entity should look like this:

```
public class Survey
{
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

Also, EF can't implement entity types declared as an interface. This won't work: `public virtual ICollection<IQuestion>` - your individual question types must all inheirit from a common abstract or concrete instance. They can still implement the interface, but your entity type properties cannot be declared that way.

I would highly recommend going through [this series of blog posts](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx) on inheritance structures in 
EF.

The way you would set up your questions entities would look like this:

```
// You can still keep the IQuestion interface around for MVC
public abstract class Question : IQuestion
{
    // ... properties ...
}

public class QuestionType1 : Question
{
    // ... properties ...
}

public class QuestionType2 : Question
{
    // ... properties ...
}

public class Survey
{
    // Note, collection of Question, not the interface.
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

Depending on how exactly you want your table structure to look, the base `Question` class may or may not be abstract. Refer to the above blog posts to see the various options - Table per Type, Table per Hierarchy, Table per Concrete.

Comment: I ended up doing just that. Now I need to figure out how to get 1 big list of all these types.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link,I think you need to set some auto policies  http://forums.asp.net/t/1816051.aspx/1

Comment: AutoPolicy is a class in the example there. I am already including the Questions.

Comment: Have you tried context.Surveys.Include("Surveys.Questions").Single(x => x.ID == id);