# EF6: "entity types cannot share table" error without any table splitting

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have created an EntityFramework 6 data context (code first) to represent some tables in a database: as for the repro code quoted below, one (`Items`) contains the items of some kind of dictionary, another (`Notes`) contains some notes which can be attached to items. An item can contain 0 or more notes. Nothing difficult here: I'll just have 1 POCO object for each table, and this is what I'm doing; yet, when initializing the database from my `DbContext` I get the error:

```
"The entity types 'EfItem' and 'Item' cannot share table 'Item' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them."
```

Now, this error seems to be meaningful for cases where several objects are mapped to the same SQL table, but this is not the case here. I have 1 and only 1 concrete object for each of the tables. So, what could be the reason of this error?

I have created a **repro solution** you can download from https://1drv.ms/u/s!AMHCfliT740PkK9H, which needs further explanation.

The main point in this solution is that I need to keep the client code totally agnostic of the storage technology of choice, which might be a RDBMS, a NoSql DB, etc. To this end, in my solution I have a "core" project, a PCL, which contains the interface for a high-level repository dealing only with interfaces. For instance, I have methods like `AddItem(IItem item)`, rather than directly using a concrete type.

This allows me to customize the concrete objects as required by the technology of choice: for instance, EF objects require "parent" navigation properties, while these would not make sense in MongoDB. Of course, the downside of this approach is having to redefine most of the concrete types, and converting them into their interface-implementing counterparts: for instance, in EF I have an `EfItem` object, which can be converted into `IItem`. Note that this object does not implement this interface, but is simply convertible to it: EF forces me to use concrete types in navigation properties (see e.g. [How to use interface properties with CodeFirst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805329/how-to-use-interface-properties-with-codefirst)), so that e.g. the item's `Notes` collection is of type `INote` in the core project, but of type `EfNote` in the EF project.

As for the EF6 project, I have added a couple of POCO objects to represent items and notes, and a `DbContext` derived class with a `DbSet` for each type (`EfItem`, `EfNote`). Note that these objects are plain, concrete types with no direct relationship to either any other concrete type, and often they are not even implementing the corresponding core interface. For instance, in the core project I have an `Item` concrete type implementing `IItem`, but it's completely independent from `EfItem` (`EfItem` has `List<EfNote> Notes` while `IItem` has `List<INote> Notes`). There is no inheritance, and no table splitting; `EfItem` is mapped to SQL table `Item`, and `EfNote` to `Note`.

Here is the essential code for my EF objects:

```
public class EfItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string SortId { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Head { get; set; }
    public short ElementCode { get; set; }
    public int LegacyNumber { get; set; }
    public int Flags { get; set; }
    public string Lemma { get; set; }
    public short Homograph { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeCreated { get; set; }
    public string CreatorId { get; set; }
    public IList<EfNote> Notes { get; set; }
}
public class EfNote
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public string BookmarkId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public byte Level { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeCreated { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my EF context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
{
    mb.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    // item
    mb.Entity<EfItem>().ToTable("Item");
    mb.Entity<EfItem>().Property(i => i.Id).IsFixedLength().HasMaxLength(32)
        .IsRequired().IsUnicode(false);
    mb.Entity<EfItem>().Property(i => i.SortId).HasMaxLength(500)
        .IsRequired().IsUnicode(false);
    mb.Entity<EfItem>().Property(i => i.ParentId).IsFixedLength().HasMaxLength(32)
        .IsUnicode(false);
    mb.Entity<EfItem>().Property(i => i.Head).HasMaxLength(50).IsUnicode(true);
    mb.Entity<EfItem>().Property(i => i.ElementCode).IsRequired();
    mb.Entity<EfItem>().Property(i => i.LegacyNumber).IsRequired();
    mb.Entity<EfItem>().Property(i => i.Flags).IsRequired();
    mb.Entity<EfItem>().Property(i => i.Lemma).HasMaxLength(200).IsRequired();
    mb.Entity<EfItem>().Property(i => i.Homograph).IsRequired();
    mb.Entity<EfItem>().Property(i => i.Content).IsRequired().IsUnicode(true)
        .HasColumnType("xml");
    mb.Entity<EfItem>().Property(i => i.TimeCreated)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasColumnType("datetime2");
    mb.Entity<EfItem>().Property(i => i.CreatorId).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
    // notes
    mb.Entity<EfNote>().ToTable("Note");
    mb.Entity<EfNote>().Property(n => n.Id).IsFixedLength().HasMaxLength(32)
        .IsRequired().IsUnicode(false);
    mb.Entity<EfNote>().Property(n => n.ItemId).IsFixedLength().HasMaxLength(32)
        .IsRequired().IsUnicode(false);
    mb.Entity<EfNote>().Property(n => n.BookmarkId)
        .HasMaxLength(50).IsUnicode(false).IsRequired();
    mb.Entity<EfNote>().Property(n => n.UserId).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
    mb.Entity<EfNote>().Property(n => n.Text).HasMaxLength(2000).IsRequired();
    mb.Entity<EfNote>().Property(n => n.Level).IsRequired();
    mb.Entity<EfNote>().Property(n => n.TimeCreated).IsRequired()
        .HasColumnType("datetime2");
    base.OnModelCreating(mb);
}
```

The SQL tables definitions are:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Item](
    [Id] [char](32) NOT NULL,
    [SortId] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [char](32) NULL,
    [Head] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ElementCode] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [LegacyNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Flags] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Lemma] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Homograph] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Content] [xml] NOT NULL,
    [CreatorId] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [TimeCreated] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Item] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Note](
    [Id] [char](32) NOT NULL,
    [ItemId] [char](32) NOT NULL,
    [BookmarkId] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Text] [nvarchar](2000) NOT NULL,
    [Level] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [TimeCreated] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Note] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)
```

Comment: Can you include the complete context and not just the OnModelCreating?

Comment: You have an `Item` in `EfNote`. That's the culprit.

Comment: Shame on me, the Item reference had escaped the refactoring... Thank you all. Gert, could you answer my post so that I can mark it as the answer? At least I could verify the general approach for such cases, I suppose that even for EF7 it will be the same when dealing with interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

In your WorkContext.cs

Change

```
public DbSet<EfItem> Items { get; set; }
```

to

```
public DbSet<EfItem> EFItems { get; set; }
```

Also in method

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)

b.Entity<EfItem>().ToTable("EFItem");
```

EF follows some naming convention between C# class and DB table name, since you have created a class named 'Item', i am afraid EF mixed class Item and EFItem together.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. The issue was caused by a simple typo as indicated in the comments before this answer was written.